# XML Deserialization Error - unexpected 'EndElement'

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer

Edit:  In case anyone comes here looking for a solution - the code below has been updated and now works correctly thanks to the accepted answer

---

Using C# targeting .NET 4.5.3, I am trying to de-serialize a Web API REST XML response to a C# class instance.

My question is: How can I fix this code so that it does what it is supposed to do - correctly de-serialize the XML response to a C# class instance.

Since I have added 'IsRequired = true' to the attributes, an exception is thrown:

```
Message: Error in line 1 position 226. 'EndElement' 'matchset' from namespace 'urn:expasy:scanprosite' is not expected. Expecting element 'n_match'.

Source: System.Runtime.Serialization

StackTrace: 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ThrowRequiredMemberMissingException(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 memberIndex, Int32 requiredIndex, XmlDictionaryString[] memberNames)
at ReadmatchsetFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlReader reader)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.<ReadAsAsyncCore>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at ConsoleApplication4.Prosite.<XmlDeserialize>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\Prosite.cs:line 22
```

Here is the output from the program to the console window (without IsRequired set):

```
n_match:
n_seq:
matchset.match.length: 0
```

Here is the HTTP request and de-serialization code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public static class Prosite
    {
        public static async Task<string> GetPrositeXML()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.expasy.org/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

                // HTTP GET
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("cgi-bin/prosite/PSScan.cgi?seq=ENTK_HUMAN&output=xml");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();//AsAsync<matchset>();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the console application code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var matchsetTask = Prosite.GetPrositeXML();

            var xmlString = matchsetTask.Result;

            var matchset = xmlString.LoadFromXML<matchset>();

            if (matchset != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("n_match: " + matchset.n_match);
                Console.WriteLine("n_seq: " + matchset.n_seq);
                Console.WriteLine("matchset.match.length: " + matchset.match.Length);

                foreach (var match in matchset.match)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("level: " + match.level);
                    Console.WriteLine("level_tag: " + match.level_tag);
                    Console.WriteLine("score: " + match.score);
                    Console.WriteLine("sequence_ac: " + match.sequence_ac);
                    Console.WriteLine("sequence_db: " + match.sequence_db);
                    Console.WriteLine("sequence_id: " + match.sequence_id);
                    Console.WriteLine("signature_ac: " + match.signature_ac);
                    Console.WriteLine("signature_id: " + match.signature_id);
                    Console.WriteLine("start: " + match.start);
                    Console.WriteLine("stop: " + match.stop);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class for the root node 'matchset' model:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    [DataContract(Name = "matchset", Namespace = "urn:expasy:scanprosite")]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "matchset", Namespace = "urn:expasy:scanprosite")]
    public class matchset
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "match")]
        [XmlElement("match")]
        public match[] match;

        [DataMember(Name = "n_match", IsRequired = true)]
        [XmlAttribute("n_match")]
        public string n_match;

        [DataMember(Name = "n_seq", IsRequired = true)]
        [XmlAttribute("n_seq")]
        public string n_seq;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the 'match' model:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    [DataContract(Name = "match", Namespace = "")]
    public class match
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "sequence_ac")]
        [XmlElement("sequence_ac")]
        public string sequence_ac;

        [DataMember(Name = "sequence_id")]
        [XmlElement("sequence_id")]
        public string sequence_id;

        [DataMember(Name = "sequence_db")]
        [XmlElement("sequence_db")]
        public string sequence_db;

        [DataMember(Name = "start")]
        [XmlElement("start")]
        public string start;

        [DataMember(Name = "stop")]
        [XmlElement("stop")]
        public string stop;

        [DataMember(Name = "signature_ac")]
        [XmlElement("signature_ac")]
        public string signature_ac;

        [DataMember(Name = "signature_id")]
        [XmlElement("signature_id")]
        public string signature_id;

        [DataMember(Name = "level_tag")]
        [XmlElement("level_tag")]
        public string level_tag;

        [DataMember(Name = "score")]
        [XmlElement("score")]
        public string score;

        [DataMember(Name = "level")]
        [XmlElement("level")]
        public string level;
    }
}
```

Here is the XML which is being deserialized:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<matchset xmlns="urn:expasy:scanprosite" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:expasy:scanprosite http://expasy.org/tools/scanprosite/scanprosite.xsd" n_match="13" n_seq="1">
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>54</start>
        <stop>169</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS50024</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>SEA</signature_id>
        <score>32.979</score>
        <level>0</level>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>183</start>
        <stop>222</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS50068</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>LDLRA_2</signature_id>
        <score>10.75</score>
        <level>0</level>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>197</start>
        <stop>221</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS01209</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>LDLRA_1</signature_id>
        <level_tag>(0)</level_tag>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>225</start>
        <stop>334</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS01180</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>CUB</signature_id>
        <score>13.293</score>
        <level>0</level>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>345</start>
        <stop>504</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS50060</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>MAM_2</signature_id>
        <score>42.203</score>
        <level>0</level>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>391</start>
        <stop>431</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS00740</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>MAM_1</signature_id>
        <level_tag>(0)</level_tag>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>524</start>
        <stop>634</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS01180</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>CUB</signature_id>
        <score>17.206</score>
        <level>0</level>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>642</start>
        <stop>678</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS50068</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>LDLRA_2</signature_id>
        <score>13.3</score>
        <level>0</level>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>655</start>
        <stop>677</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS01209</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>LDLRA_1</signature_id>
        <level_tag>(0)</level_tag>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>678</start>
        <stop>788</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS50287</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>SRCR_2</signature_id>
        <score>16.02</score>
        <level>0</level>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>785</start>
        <stop>1019</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS50240</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>TRYPSIN_DOM</signature_id>
        <score>39.104</score>
        <level>0</level>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>821</start>
        <stop>826</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS00134</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>TRYPSIN_HIS</signature_id>
        <level_tag>(0)</level_tag>
    </match>
    <match>
        <sequence_ac>P98073</sequence_ac>
        <sequence_id>ENTK_HUMAN</sequence_id>
        <sequence_db>sp</sequence_db>
        <start>965</start>
        <stop>976</stop>
        <signature_ac>PS00135</signature_ac>
        <signature_id>TRYPSIN_SER</signature_id>
        <level_tag>(0)</level_tag>
    </match>
</matchset>
```

XmlSerializationHelper class provided by @dbc in the accepted answer:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public static class XmlSerializationHelper
    {
        public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, bool omitStandardNamespaces)
        {
            using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;        // For cosmetic purposes.
                settings.IndentChars = "    "; // For cosmetic purposes.
                using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                {
                    if (omitStandardNamespaces)
                    {
                        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                        ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
                        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
                    }
                }
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }

        public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer)
        {
            return GetXml(obj, serializer, false);
        }

        public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, bool omitNamespace)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            return GetXml(obj, serializer, omitNamespace);
        }

        public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj)
        {
            return GetXml(obj, false);
        }

        public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString)
        {
            return xmlString.LoadFromXML<T>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)));
        }

        public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString, XmlSerializer serial)
        {
            T returnValue = default(T);

            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                object result = serial.Deserialize(reader);
                if (result is T)
                {
                    returnValue = (T)result;
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: That isn't valid xml, is it? the `xmlns` is ... gibberish? This is almost certainly xml namespace related. `<foo>` is not the same as `<alias:foo>` or `<foo xmlns="urn">`. I'm guessing you mean `xmlns="urn:expasy:scanprosite"` ? or...?

Comment: @MarcGravell I had pasted the XML into Visual Studio to tab indent it for Stack Overflow.  Auto-formatting must have changed some of the text.  I have re-pasted it now.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classes contain a mixture of data contract attributes and `XmlSerializer` attributes.  I am going to assume you are using `XmlSerializer` because of the application of the attribute `[XmlSerializerFormat]`.  In that case, you need to:

1. Put back the `XmlRoot` attribute on `matchset`:

   ```
   [Serializable]
   [XmlSerializerFormat]
   [DataContract(Name = "matchset", Namespace = "urn:expasy:scanprosite")]
   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "matchset", Namespace = "urn:expasy:scanprosite")]
   public class matchset
   {
   ```
2. Change `public match[] match` to `XmlElement`:

   ```
       [DataMember(Name = "match")]
       [XmlElement("match")]
       public match[] match
       {
           get { return this.matchField; }
           set { this.matchField = value; }
       }
   ```

After doing so I am able to read the xml string given in your post.

The answer is based on your original classes not your modified classes.  Here is how I tested it:

```
public static class TestMatchSet
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var xml = XmlProvider.GetXml(); // Returns the long XML string from the post.
        var matchSet = XmlSerializationHelper.LoadFromXML<matchset>(xml);

        Debug.WriteLine(matchSet.GetXml());
    }
}

public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, bool omitStandardNamespaces)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;        // For cosmetic purposes.
            settings.IndentChars = "    "; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                if (omitStandardNamespaces)
                {
                    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                    ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
                }
                else
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
                }
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer)
    {
        return GetXml(obj, serializer, false);
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, bool omitNamespace)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        return GetXml(obj, serializer, omitNamespace);
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return GetXml(obj, false);
    }

    public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString)
    {
        return xmlString.LoadFromXML<T>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)));
    }

    public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString, XmlSerializer serial)
    {
        T returnValue = default(T);

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            object result = serial.Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
            {
                returnValue = (T)result;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made the two changes you suggested - however I still receive the same exception?  If you have it working - is there any chance you could paste the entire code please or do you have any other suggestions?  Thank you

Comment: I thought your problem was that the match array was not read?  You added the "IsRequired" after I copied your classes and debugged them.  Now I'll have to start again?

Comment: Yes the match array isn't read, but none of the properties are read either.  However, making the changes you suggested didn't make the match array read. Just that by itself would be an improvement.

Comment: @Aalawlx - see edit.  The answer is based on your original classes + XML.  Are you using `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`?  What is the full text of the exception you receive?

Comment: You are right in that I want to use XmlSerializer as there are attributes in the matchset tag which need to be read and I heard that DataContractSerializer cannot read tag attributes?  Thanks for that code, I'll try it out.

Comment: @Aalawlx - From the exception traceback you're using `DataContractSerializer` not `XmlSerializer`.  `DataContractSerializer` doesn't easily allow you to specify that certain properties are attributes, and doesn't easily allow you to format lists with one level instead of two.  I suggest switching to `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: That would explain everything, I had read that if you apply the [XmlSerializerFormat] tag then XmlSerializer would automatically be  used - is this not the case?

Comment: With the help of your code I have fixed the problem, thank you very much, hours of headache fixed!

Comment: @Aalawlx - Great!  How did you succeed in changing serializer?  Pass an appropriate [`XmlMediaTypeFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.xmlmediatypeformatter%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh943959%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)?

Comment: I changed response.Content.ReadAsAsync() to response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() and passed the XML to your XmlSerializationHelper class and it worked!  I have also updated the code above to the working version.  Thanks again!